# What is Shopify Section object alternative?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I am trying to make a shopify theme extension where I have radio button and radio button form should hit `form="{{ product_form_id }}"` and product_form_id is coming from `{%- assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id -%}` since shopify restricted section object in theme extension how can I use this id ? I am absolutely new in shopify.